# What conditions can be checked in the "Found" options for a Watson Assistant dialog's slots?

Tags: watson-assistant

What kinds of conditions can go in the "If Assistant Recognizes" entries in the "Found" options for a Watson Assistant dialog's slots?

For example, if Assistant recognizes `@sys-location` how do do I configure responses based on the recognized value?

The following does not work:

[image]

Comment: I think what's stumping me here is that apparently `$where:boston` or `@sys-location:boston` don't work if "Boston" is recognized. How do I enforce case-insensitive comparisons?

Comment: And patterns like `@sys-time.after('21:00:00')` don't seem to be recognized, even if they are [mentioned in the docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-slots#dialog-slots-handler-next-steps).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for "if assistant recognizes" is to use entities. In your example above, where you might want to customize a response based on a specific location, you could define a `@location` entity and add target values like `@location:germany` and `@location:france`. One benefit to this approach is that you can use entity value synonyms to easily expand recognition of common alternate names (e.g. for `@location:germany` you could have synonyms like `deutschland`, `berlin`, `bavaria`, etc.) so your bot can handle those without you needing to build all of that out in the dialog logic.